# Sublime Text 2 - Key Binding for Open Recent?

Tags: sublimetext

How can I map Open Recent, or "open last file" to a keyboard shortcut?

This is my pitiful attempt so far:

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+r"], "command": "open_recent"}
```

I tried looking at the console (Ctrl-`) while using Open Recent but it doesn't display anything.

In general, how does one go about adding key bindings?  And is there a more appropriate place that Stack Overflow for this question?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try out a couple of packages:

https://github.com/spadgos/sublime-OpenRecentFiles

or:

https://github.com/paccator/GotoRecent

And the easiest way to install them is with this package control, package:
http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation

That should give you what you want...

Answer (score 3):

Key bindings should be added to the User key-binding preferences. Adding to the default settings will also work, but the settings will be overwritten when a new version of Sublime Text 2 is installed.

Your attempt matches the general structure of a Sublime Text key-binding, but "open_recent" isn't a valid command. From what I can find in the documentation, I think the Open Recent menu keeps track of the different file names then calls open on whichever file is selected, instead of calling an open_recent command.

If there isn't a way to get the name of the most recent file, you could probably write an extension that kept track of the most recent file and then opened it, but that probably be a fairly kludgy solution.

Comment: I feared this might be true.  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

The command is `reopen_last_file`. So you should add something like this:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "reopen_last_file" },
```

Little PS: I'm using `ctrl+shift+t`, so that the shortcut for reopening the last document is consistent across my browser, IDE and editor.

Comment: Isn't that what is mapped to Cmd-Shift-T by default? - { "keys": ["super+shift+t"], "command": "reopen_last_file" }.  It's a while since I wrote this question but I think I was after the actual Open Recent menu.  I guess just hitting Cmd-Shift-T a bunch of times is sufficient to find whatever it is you are looking for.  Perhaps I didn't know about that when I wrote this question.  Thanks though!

Comment: Well, it is `ctrl+shift+t`in my `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file. If there is a command for the functionality you are looking for (show the list of recent files), you should be able to assign it to a keymap. But I couldn't find such a function using the command palette (`ctrl+shift+p`).

Comment: That is the best answer here 
thanks for your time and efforts